# Wordpress Mysql numbering values in replace

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am modifying wp_postmeta table for a wordpress site .
I have a lot of rows like this.

`meta_key` for gallery for one `post_id`

[image]

Now I want to change the value of meta_key And add a unique number to each one Like
fave_property_images_1 ,fave_property_images_2 , fave_property_images_3 ... for every post

I have long searched for a way in mysql

I can do it through php but it will take longer time

Comment: If my answer helps you, please don't forget to vote/mark as answer :) Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Actually, no, I apologize for that. I may not have explained the situation well.
I think it is more involved than this, in the end I wrote a php script and did what was required

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same id field that you know is unique.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET meta_key = CONCAT(meta_key,"_",meta_id);
```

without `WHERE`.

Or if you really want in your way:

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE your_table SET meta_key = CONCAT(meta_key,"_",@i:=@i+1);
```